# Creating an Invoice in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I have only dabbled with Excel and not much in quite some time now.

I have an Excel Invoice laid out so Column A is a name of a job and each row in column A can be a different job.

Now column B through N are dates of when that job was done.

What I want to do is assign a monetary value to any date that is entered in cells from column B-N, and see the dates in the cells and have Column O tally the totals for cells B-N on that row and then total the totals at the bottom of column O.

Here is a screen shot to help. Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Skipping the invoice part, the question -ask asked- basically is:

I want to count how often I wrote something in colum B to N.  
Then multiple that with the cost mentioned in A,  
and add all these items.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772225/how-do-i-get-countifs-to-select-all-non-blank-cells-in-excel might be a good point to start, as is the SUM fucntion).

Comment: Do values in column N show the desired or current output? If it's the current, please add also desired one. Storing price and description in the same cell (like in column A) makes your like far more difficult, can you split it?

Answer (score 2):

A few thing you would want to do first:

- Separate Job Title and Job Amount into two columns.
- Create and additional column to count the cells range where a date is
  being input
- Format appropriate cells for currency

This will allow you to use a formula to automatically calculate your answer. I am attaching pictures you can see.

[image: Overall View]

Column O is a count formula and Column P is simple multiplication. Cell P6 is a sum function to get your grand total.

[image: Formulas]

Comment: There should be no need to have a Qty column (unless OP wants it, of course); just use `=B2*COUNT(C2:N2)` (and similar for the other rows) directly.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Very true.

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate the pay from Job Title, this will make your life easier and allow you to use excel formulas
2. enter **=COUNTA(C2:N2)*A2** in the cell **O2** and hit enter. this will count non-empty cells in the range **C2 to N2** and multiply the number with **A2**
3. Copy the cell O2 to O3, O4 and so on. excel will automatically change the value of the formula to suit the row you're pasting in.

[image]

in this example I typed **=SUM(O2:O5)**, but you can just type **=SUM(** and then use your mouse to select a range of cells by clicking and holding, once you release the mouse button, hit enter and excel will add the numbers in the cell range you selected.

if anything's not clear I'm here to help.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I will try the 3 different methods listed. I see uses for all and adding a column to show qty. might be a good idea. I was definitely trying to make it harder than it needed to be. Thank you all.

Comment: btw =COUNTA(C2:N2) will show the qty too I just skipped a step and multiplied it by pay directly